# Vue js computed properties evaluation order

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a component which uses 'data1' props.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <component1 :data='data1'><component1>
    </div>
<template>
```

This data1 is a computed property which needs another computed data for calculating one of its values:

```
computed: {

    componentInfo: function() {
        return this.$store.state.componentData;
    }

    data1: function() {
        return {value1: this.componentInfo.value1, ... other values}
    }
}
```

My problem is that the component tries to evaluate data1 value before getting the componentInfo from the store (which causes an error since this.componentInfo is still undefined)

How should such a scenario be treated?

Comment: Maybe set up a default value for the prop: `props: { data: { default: null /* or default values*/ } }`

Comment: Computed properties should be evaluated only when they're needed. You can use a computed property inside another one and it should work fine. is the data definitely in the `$store`? One way to double check this is to use `this.$store.state.componentData.value1` directly in your `data1` method.

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting? It seems highly unlikely that the store is not initialized before the computed property.

Comment: @RossWilson Thanks, You were right. this is a simplified example but I had a problem with the exact path to the object in the store.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to handle. Just add an extra `if` to computed property:

```
data1 () {
  if (this.componentInfo) { // check if it exists
    return { value1: this.componentInfo.value1, ... other values }
  } else {
    return {} // some default value
  }
}
```